2sxc new entity: retrieve new entity from modal dialog
In 2sxc app v17.x, From my view Im using js call $2sxc.cms.run('new',...) to create new contenttype item, after save and close dialog, how i can get new created entityId after modal dialog closed.
I try .then promise but not found new entityid

Can you share some of your existing code so we can see what you are doing? Just to verify, your question is on the front-end, right? You are doing this from JS in the browser? Also, do you already have your own API established - or are you trying to do this entirely with the provided 2sxc JS API tools?

The closing dialog can't give you any data back - also not an ID - unfortunately.
But I believe to remember that there is a solution ;)
AFAIK you can pre-generate a GUID for your new entity and include that in the open-dialog-request. After that you can get the created element using that GUID. I don't remember the specifics, but if you can't get it to work then please open an issue.

Oh, thanks so much, im solved

great - best mark as answered.

maybe you can also add a bit more detail how it works - for the next person with the same question.
